# How to work with CURSOR in PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have table `RADNIK` filled with some test data and containing 21 rows. When I execute simple `SELECT` command like: `SELECT ime, prz, plt FROM RADNIK;` it gives me expected result.

I decided to learn PL/SQL and I wrote this code:

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR c_radnik IS 
        SELECT ime, prz, plt FROM RADNIK;
    rec_radnik c_radnik%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    OPEN c_radnik;
    LOOP
        FETCH c_radnik INTO rec_radnik;
        EXIT WHEN c_radnik%NOTFOUND;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rec_radnik.ime || ' ' 
            || rec_radnik.prz || ' ' 
            || rec_radnik.plt);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE c_radnik;
END;
```

After executing this code, I got only message: `PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.`

I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: `set serveroutput on` to se result of the `dbms_output.put_line()`

Comment: This question isn't duplicate with that question. In my case DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('example') doesn't print anything. In duplicate question it prints but incorrect.